# Setting z_order when working with ConnectionPatch

Tags: matplotlib

I am trying to produce a figure where red line is not going to be visible inside the green rectangle (i.e. within the middle panel). Setting z order seems to be in effect only for the lower panel (subplot) and it is ignored for the upper and middle one. Can anyone help with this please.

Alternatively, what would also work for me is, if I plot two subplots: top and bottom, and the piece of line that connects points X (from the bottom) and Y (from the top subplot) does not get plotted in the region which is between two places. In other words, line looks as a broken line going from X to the top of bottom panel, then having some skip and then continuing from min_y in top panel and going all the way  to Y. 
I am planning to achieve this by setting color of rectangle to be white so that it overwrites these lines (but this does not work).

```
from matplotlib.patches import ConnectionPatch
import matplotlib.patches as patches
from matplotlib.patches import Rectangle
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


fig, (ax_upper, ax_middle, ax_lower) = plt.subplots(3, 1, sharey = False)

ax_upper.spines['top'].set_visible(False)
ax_upper.spines['bottom'].set_visible(False)
ax_upper.spines['right'].set_visible(False)
ax_upper.get_xaxis().set_ticks([])

ax_middle.spines['left'].set_visible(False)
ax_middle.spines['right'].set_visible(False)
ax_middle.spines['top'].set_visible(False)
ax_middle.spines['bottom'].set_visible(False)
ax_middle.get_xaxis().set_ticks([])
ax_middle.get_yaxis().set_ticks([])

ax_lower.spines['top'].set_visible(False)
ax_lower.spines['right'].set_visible(False)

ax_upper.set_ylim(10, 100)
ax_lower.set_ylim(0, 10)
ax_lower.set_xlim(0, 100)
ax_upper.set_xlim(0, 100)

con = ConnectionPatch(xyA = (2, 2), xyB = (80,90), coordsA = "data", coordsB = "data", axesA = ax_lower, axesB = ax_upper)
ax_lower.add_artist(con)
con.set_zorder(1)
con.set_color("red")
con.set_linewidth(3)


con = ConnectionPatch(xyA = (95,5), xyB = (80, 90), coordsA = "data", coordsB = "data", axesA = ax_lower, axesB = ax_upper, lw=1)
ax_lower.add_artist(con)
con.set_zorder(1)
con.set_color("red")
con.set_linewidth(3)


ax_lower.plot([2],  [2],  marker="o", color = "red")
ax_upper.plot([80], [90], marker="o", color = "red", zorder = 2)
ax_lower.plot([95], [5],  marker="o", color = "red")

ax_upper.plot([0,0],[0,0], label="class A", color = "red", zorder=1, marker = "o", )
ax_upper.legend(loc='upper left')

rect = Rectangle((0,0), 1, 1, linewidth=1, edgecolor='black', facecolor='green', zorder = 3)
ax_middle.add_patch(rect)

plt.show()
```

[example output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zX2wl.jpg)

Comment: Does `ax_middle.set_zorder(5)` not work?

Comment: Yes, great! One last question that I have is, if I add this blue line (see attachment) is it possible to make blue line entirely visible?
[Here is image that I refer to above][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HcXv3.png

Comment: In that case you would need to add the connectionpatch to the figure instead of the axes.

Comment: Thank you for the help. That works. Alternatively, one can also plot three separate vertical lines (one per axes) and these combined together provide a desired line. This is of course conditioned on setting spacing between axes to zero.